# How to provide a path of an html file to src attribute of Iframe in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I am having problem in providing a path to the IFrame src.

I hav kept my html file in the same directory.But still i dont get it

I wrote like this:

```
  <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" src="Dancing.htm" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></iframe>
```

But it gives me error as Resource Not found However if i write a view(.cshtml) page rather than HTM page it is loaded properly i am not undertsanding why this is happening

Please Help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to locate your *.html files out of Views folder.

Create HTML folder and copy your Dancing.htm file to that folder

```
/HTML/Dancing.htm
```

---

```
<iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" src="@Url.Content("~/HTML/Dancing.htm")" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Shal i make a folder For Html Files and then How shal i route it

Comment: Hey thanx its workin but can u tell me how shal write this in my javascript:
  filename = $(this).text() + ".htm";
  filename1 = '@Url.Content("~/HTML/"+filename)';
This doesnot work

Comment: razor tags are build time codes. you can not manipulate it on runtime. you can create a html helper that returns url of element.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article - [URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx). Your cshtml page is routed. But htm not. So looks like it will work if you add path with directory name. From other hand you can add custom router. But to my mind it isn't good idea to keep htm and cshtml in same place.

Comment: Can u tell me a way in which i dont hav to go the Controller..like without goin to the controller the path must be fetched foran html page